# Mandarin chinese: syllable pronunciation training

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation

Is there free mp3 resources of all combinations of syllables (1consonnant + 1vowel) in different tones?

Here an example of syllables:
[All Possible Syllables in Mandarin Chinese](http://www.zein.se/patrick/chinen8p.html#all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer to my question:

The audio from the second link is better that the first

1. http://lost-theory.org/chinese/phonetics/
2. http://www.uvm.edu/~chinese/pinyin.htm

And this one is of better quality:

https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-pinyin-chart.php

Comment: Nice. These kinds of charts typically neglect the widespread 儿 "er" sound that you'll often find modifying the ends of words. Though it is left off in dictionaries, and is said to be optional, some listeners will have a hard time understanding certain phrases without it. You'll also need to learn how to leave some syllables unstressed, in which case their tone mark is largely irrelevant, depending more on the tone of the preceding syllable. Don't focus on that though. Just spend a lot of time listening to Chinese conversations and watching Chinese TV. You'll get it.

Comment: And some speakers will have difficulty understanding certain phrases with the widespread 儿话音 suffix